# Cannot install dotnet-sdk2.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: .net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I was trying to install dotnet-sdk2.1.101 on my Ubuntu 16.04 server today but following error occured: 
*"dotnet-sdk-2.1.101 : Depends: aspnetcore-store-2.0.6 but it  but it is not going to be installed"*

Steps taken: (followed instructions on microsoft website):

- wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
- sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
- sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: This may be better asked on StackExchange's https://askubuntu.com/ instead of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

Following a guide on [Upgrading to dotnet core 2.1.4 on Ubuntu 16.04](http://colhountech-linux.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/upgrading-to-dotnet-core-2-1-on-ubuntu-16-04/) resolved this issue on my end:

> First, Setup the package manager.
>
> `$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg`
>
> `$ sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg`
>
> `$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'`
>
> `$ sudo apt-get update`
>
> Next, Install .NET Core 2.x
>
> `$ sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.4`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my own issue following these below steps:

> wget -q packages-microsoft-prod.deb https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
>
> sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
>
> sudo apt-get update –y
>
> sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.101

Answer (score 0):

For me previous didn't help.

But for me worked the next:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/icu/libicu57_57.1-6+deb9u2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libicu57_57.1-6+deb9u2_amd64.deb 

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu60_60.2-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libicu60_60.2-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1
```

I don't quite understand did I need 2 versions of libicu, but after 1st it required the 2nd one.